# Restrict layers in attribute table widget in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, attribute-table, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I'm building a webapp, where you can change from several map services. In every map service there are several layers with same naming, but not with the same number of layers. I cannot set the attribute table widget up in Web AppBuilder, because the JSON too hardcoded. I'm really new in JavaScript.

I would make a list in js, what contains the allowed layer's  name:

```
layersToShow: [Layer1, Layer2, Layer3]
```

in the widget's _ResourceManager.js

I think here is the section from the manager, where I could repoint the reader. But I don't know how. I would add all the possible allowed layers to the list, and the js may fail to get the layerinfo. How would you accoplish this?

```
      if (updateConfig) {
        if (this.config.layerInfos.length === 0) {
          // if no config only display visible layers  ,egy tombot csinalok es amikor itt filterel, akkor egy consistal kerem le a tombbol
          var configLayerInfos = attrUtils.getConfigInfosFromLayerInfos(layerInfos);
          this.config.layerInfos = array.filter(configLayerInfos, function(layer) {
            return layer.show;
          });
```